# Having trouble using NSolve inside Module

Tags: differential-equations

```
Y = 2*10^11;
Iyy = 8.333*10^-6;
L = 4;
stiff = (Y*Iyy)/L^3;
k = {0.01, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 
  800, 1*^3, 2*^3, 4*^3, 5*^3, 10*^3, 15*^3, 20*^3, 30*^3, 40*^3, 
  70*^3, 1*^5, 1*^6, 1*^8, 
  1*^12};(*THIS IS THE FIRST  PARAMETER REPRESENTS  STIFFNESS *)
m = {0.01, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 
  800, 1*^3, 2*^3, 4*^3, 5*^3, 10*^3, 15*^3, 20*^3, 30*^3, 40*^3, 
  70*^3, 1*^5, 1*^6, 1*^8, 1*^12};
eq = (1/(2*b^3))*(((Sin[b*(1 - z)]*Sin[b*z])/
      Sin[b]) - ((Sinh[b*(1 - z)]*Sinh[b*z])/
      Sinh[b]));(*Green's function *)
eq1[i_, j_] := (1 - (((m[[j]]*b^4)/(1 - m[[j]]/k[[i]]*b^4))*eq));
f[z_] := Module[{sol, test, resu, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, mode1, mode2, 
    mode3, mode4, mode5, impedence, imp}, 
   sol = Flatten@Table[eq1[i, j], {i, 30}, {j, 30}];
    test = NSolve[# == 0 && 0 < b < 70, b] & /@ sol; 
     resu = Sort@#[[;; 5]] & /@ (b /. # & /@ test);
   b1 = resu[[All, 1]];
   b2 = resu[[All, 2]];
   b3 = resu[[All, 3]];
   b4 = resu[[All, 4]];
   b5 = resu[[All, 5]];
   mode1 = ArrayReshape[b1, {30, 30}];
   mode2 = ArrayReshape[b2, {30, 30}];
   mode3 = ArrayReshape[b3, {30, 30}];
   mode4 = ArrayReshape[b4, {30, 30}];
   mode5 = ArrayReshape[b5, {30, 30}];
   impedence = ConstantArray[0, {30, 30}];
   For[i = 1, i < 31, i++, 
    For[j = 1, j < 31, j++, 
     impedence[[i, 
       j]] = (k[[i]] - 
        m[[j]]*(mode1[[i, j]])^4*(Iyy*Y)/(7850*0.1^2*L^4))]];
   imp = Flatten[ArrayReshape[impedence, {1, 900}]]; 
   Return[{sol, test, resu, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, mode1, mode2, mode3, 
     mode4, mode5, impedence, imp}]];
f[0.1]
```

I am using `Module` for the first time in Mathematica.

I have embedded `NSolve` for solving `eq1` (which happened to be the function of `k` `m` and `z` )inside `Module`, but I am getting an error  `This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve.` .What is the reason for this failure? Are there any other function which can be used for finding the first five roots of the `eq1`. `FindRoots` is not the best choice since I have to give the initial guess.

Comment: I do not think that `Module` is your problem here. Did you realize that the equations you feed into `NSolve` contain two variables, $b$ and $z$? Are you missing a numerical definition for $z$? Even if you did, I am not sure that it would make sense trying to `Sort` those symbolic solutions. Have you tried running each line of code on its own before wrapping the whole thing in a `Module`?

Comment: b is unknown and z is the input to the module. The only unknown is b, if we solve for b, we will get the solution of eq1. Yes I tried running each line of code on its own before wrapping the whole thing in a Module, and it is working and no problem with NSolve  there.

Comment: I tested it but why it is not taking value for z? Since I am new to module  am I making any mistake

Comment: I'd recommend you make `eq` and `eq1` explicitly functions of `z` and `b`.

Comment: yes, I get rid of the module and checked that it is not replacing. I guess I am doing some mistake

Comment: as explanation the `z` as a function "argument" only gets applied where it appears explicitly in the function body before evaluation.  An alternate approach to fix this is to use some other symbol for the argument `f[zarg_]:= ..` , then apply it where needed, eg,  `eq/.z->zarg`

Comment: @george I implemented it and it is working. thanks for the suggestions and your time.